# Twilio app to app Call When App closed or killed in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, twilio, voip, twilio-click-to-call

I have done All Registration step from twilio client SDK for app to app call and i have successfully established call with two device.
I am happy with twilio client SDK integrate with our server setup.

**See Below Logs When successfully Connection.**

```
06-15 10:27:41.268 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: account information : com.twilio.client.impl.session.Account@ca8c233
06-15 10:27:41.268 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: onRegistrationState for Account id: 1
06-15 10:27:41.269 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: RegistrationInfo Code 200
06-15 10:27:41.269 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: RegistrationInfo success true
06-15 10:27:41.269 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: RegistrationInfo expiration 100
06-15 10:27:41.269 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: Client registered successfully
```

**See Below Logs When Incoming Call (app is open/running state)**

```
06-15 10:27:59.089 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: onCallSDPCreated notification received
            06-15 10:27:59.098 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/CallControlManager: Incoming call notification received
            06-15 10:27:59.103 12325-12742/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/MediaManager: playing sound INCOMING as id 1
            06-15 10:27:59.108 12325-13082/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/AwesomeSoundPoolPlayThread: play thread starting
            06-15 10:27:59.115 12325-12325/com.twilio.client.quickstart E/ClentActvity: onResume
            06-15 10:27:59.122 12325-12325/com.twilio.client.quickstart E/ClentActvity: device :com.twilio.client.impl.DeviceImpl@57a00d9
            06-15 10:27:59.122 12325-12325/com.twilio.client.quickstart E/ClentActvity: incomingConnection :com.twilio.client.impl.InternalConnectionImpl@20aaa9e
```

> All things are working fine, Now i need help for How can i manage app
> to app call in My Bellow Case :
>
> 1. **When App Closed.**
> 2. **When App Killed.**
> 3. **When Token Expired.**

Comment: you can observe those events from android .. and you can do app app call?

Comment: thanks for replay, yes i have done all things are for app to app call now problem in when app closed state !!

Answer (score 3):

1-2: At the moment, the Android SDK does not provide callback handlers for device state change.

You can receive events from the [`DeviceListener`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/DeviceListener) and handle those accordingly.

3. Some people choose to [generate a new token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) for every call or every so often. But you'll know a token is expired upon receiving the [31205 error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors).

Comment: Is it Possible or Not when app closed to receive incoming call in android ?
if yes then How ? or if No then give me correct reason. thanks.